# TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not int

Tags: python, image, pytorch, dataset, conv-neural-network

I am new here and I am trying to learn python for deep learning using pytorch. and I want to use the pytorch writing custom datasets. I tried a simple task first I want to read images in a folder and then visualize them.

This is what I tried:

```
class msr_data(Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, image_path, transform=None):
        self.image_path = image_path
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.msr_data)

    def __getitem__(self, image_path):
        images = []
        for filename in os.listdir(image_path):
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_path,filename))
            im_rgb = img[:, :, ::-1]
            images.append(im_rgb)   
        for i in images:
            data=np.array(im_rgb)
return data
 
dataset = msr_data(image_path='files', transform=None)
for i, sample in enumerate(dataset):
    print(i)
    plt.imshow(sample)
    plt.show()
```

But I got the above error. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Every pytorch `Dataset` or inheritor from this class must implement a  `__getitem__` function, which expects an integer index as input. You should use this integer to index the dataset and it's attributes, which you initialize in `__init__`.

Your dataset has problems. They are:

1. `image_path` is not used to do anything (e.g. count the number of data examples and store these paths) in `__init__`. You enumerate files in `__getitem__`, which is wasteful because you'll have to do this operation every time you index an item from the dataset.
2. `__len__` doesn't return the correct length and
3. Moreover `__len__` calls `self.msr_data`. The `msr_data` class doesn't have an attribute `self.msr_data`. If it did, this would be an infinitely recursive call.
4. `__getitem__` receives, by your expectation, a string. This violates the function prototype defined by the parent pytorch.data.Dataset class which expects an integer index.

- Transform is never used.

Correcting these issues (except the transform):

```
class MSR_Data(Dataset):    # Capitals preferred for class names but this is stylistic only

   def __init__(self, image_path, transform=None):

       # store all image paths in a list
       image_files = [os.path.join(image_path,item) for item in os.listdir(image_path)]
       
       self.images = []
       for path in image_files: 
              img = cv2.imread(path)
              im_rgb = img[:, :, ::-1]
              self.images.append(im_rgb)

       # store transform
       self.transform = transform

   def __len__(self):
       return len(self.images)

   def __getitem__(self,idx):
       data=np.array(self.images[idx])
       return data
```

dataset = msr_data(image_path='files',transform=None)
for i,sample in enumerate(dataset):
print(i)
plt.imshow(sample)
plt.show()

After these changes you should have a MWE of a pytorch dataset, though without a transform, labels, partitioning, or any other dynamic augmentations this class offers no advantage over a simple list (in fact it is just a wrapper class around a list of images). I recommend to check out [pytorch's tutorial on dataset objects.](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html)